# How to create PHP Mysql daily report without duplicating agent name?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

**Table Structure bill**

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bill` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `agent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `cheque` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `bill`
--

INSERT INTO `bill` (`id`, `agent_id`, `date`, `amount`, `cheque`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2013-01-01', 10, 15),
(2, 1, '2013-01-01', 10, 0),
(3, 2, '2013-01-02', 10, 0),
(4, 1, '2013-01-03', 12, 0),
(5, 3, '2013-01-04', 100, 0),
(6, 2, '2013-01-05', 14, 0),
(7, 5, '2013-01-05', 18, 0),
(8, 7, '2013-01-05', 22, 0),
(9, 6, '2013-01-04', 19, 0),
(10, 6, '2013-01-06', 20, 0),
(11, 5, '2013-01-07', 21, 0),
(12, 6, '2013-01-08', 11, 0),
(13, 7, '2013-02-09', 19, 0),
(14, 6, '2013-01-10', 150, 0),
(15, 1, '2012-12-31', 100, 0),
(16, 1, '2012-01-11', 500, 20),
(17, 1, '2013-02-01', 210, 0),
(18, 1, '2013-02-18', 100, 0),
(19, 6, '2013-01-31', 100, 0),
(20, 3, '2013-01-11', 250, 50);
```

**Table Structure bill_agents**

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bill_agents` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `target` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `join_date` date NOT NULL,
  `resign_date` date NOT NULL,
  `hide` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `bill_agents`
--

INSERT INTO `bill_agents` (`id`, `name`, `target`, `join_date`, `resign_date`, `hide`) VALUES
(1, 'Agent 1', 10, '2013-01-01', '0000-00-00', 0),
(2, 'Agent 2', 5000, '2013-01-01', '0000-00-00', 0),
(3, 'Agent 3', 5000, '2013-01-01', '0000-00-00', 0),
(4, 'Agent 4', 5000, '2013-01-03', '2013-01-06', 0),
(5, 'Agent 5', 5000, '2013-01-01', '0000-00-00', 0),
(6, 'Agent 6', 5000, '2013-01-02', '0000-00-00', 0),
(7, 'Agent 7', 5000, '2013-01-02', '0000-00-00', 1);
```

My Current result: [image: current result]

( 1-31 are the dates)  with following code

```php
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="1">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <?php
for ($i=01; $i<=31; $i++)
  {?>
    <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
    <?php

  }
?>
    <td>Total</td>
  </tr>
  <?php 
    $query4 = "SELECT DISTINCT bill.agent_id, bill.date, SUM(bill.amount + bill.cheque) AS total, bill_agents.id,bill_agents.name ".
        "FROM bill, bill_agents ".
        "WHERE bill.agent_id = bill_agents.id AND YEAR(date)  = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) ".
        "GROUP BY bill.agent_id , DATE(bill.date)   ".
        "ORDER BY bill.date ASC ";
     $result4 = mysql_query($query4) or die('Error, query failed1'); 
    if  (mysql_num_rows($result4)>0){
    mysql_data_seek($result4, 0);   

?>
  <?php $total_1 = 0;  while($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($result4, MYSQL_ASSOC)){?>
  <?php $date =    $row4['date'];

    $var = $date;
    $date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($var) );
    $date=substr($date, 0, -8); 

    echo $date;

    ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row4['name']; ?></td>
    <?php
for ($i=01; $i<=31; $i++)
  {?>
    <td><?php if ($date == $i) echo $row4['total']; ?></td>
    <?php

  }
?>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } } ?>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="31"></td>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I am trying to create is i don't want to duplicate  agents name **if more than one entry in database it should come under the current date** only and grand total also should be   .  how is is it possible  sql query ? or do i need to create with other code?

Here is an example what i am trying to create [image: expected result]

Comment: ORDER BY user_id, bill_date... Then loop through the results creating a new row every time the user_id changes. Also lose the ' "..\n ." ' stuff. It's unecessary!

Comment: Then how do i  get desired  result ? is it not possible  with current php code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$select_agent_id = mysql_query("select agent_id from bill group by agent_id");
while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($select_agent_id)) {
    $agent_id[] = $fetch['agent_id'];
}
$number_of_agents = count($agent_id);

    $output = "<table border='2px' bordercolor='#460000'>";
    $output .="<tr>";
    $output .="<td>Name</td>";
    for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++) {
        $output .="<td>".$i."</td>";
    }
    $output .="<td>Total</td>"; 
    $output .="</tr>";

foreach($agent_id as $id) {

    $select_records = mysql_query("select *, sum(amount) from bill where agent_id = $id 
                      and date between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-31' group by date");

    $select_agent_name = mysql_query("select name from bill_agents where id=$id");
    $fetch_name = mysql_fetch_array($select_agent_name);
    $agent_name = $fetch_name['name'];


    $rows_count = mysql_num_rows($select_records);
    while($fetch_dates = mysql_fetch_array($select_records)) {
        $dates[] =substr($fetch_dates['date'],-2,2);
        $amounts[] = $fetch_dates['sum(amount)'];
    }
    $output .= "<tr>";
    $output .="<td>".$agent_name."</td>";

    for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++) {

        if(!empty($dates)) {

            if($i==$dates[0]) {
                $output .="<td>".$amounts[0]."</td>";
                array_shift($amounts);
                array_shift($dates);
            } else {
                $output .= "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
            }
        } else {
            $output .= "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        }

    }
    $total_amount_query = mysql_query("select sum(amount) from bill where agent_id = $id 
                      and date between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-31' group by agent_id");
    $fetch_total_amount = mysql_fetch_array($total_amount_query);
    $output .="<td>".$fetch_total_amount['sum(amount)']."</td>";                  
    $output .= "</tr>";

}
$output .="</table>";
echo $output;
```

@Preethu Alex : Above is you code. Please check and let me know. Hope this helps. I have not done any checking for **SQL INJECTION**. I have also given some dates as static in the query. Please modify it accodingly

Comment: This is what i was looking for last 2 week and its is working perfecly

Comment: Can i have one more question in this code how to order by total amount ascending ?

Comment: Sure. Just give me some time

Comment: The code you written is working perfect but i want to displaythe order by total amount see this expample (total amount) http://i.stack.imgur.com/N13ae.jpg

Comment: @Preethu Alex : Use "Order by sum(amount) ASC" in the queries